# How to divide the layout in 3 parts?

Tags: css, html

i have a scene where i want to divide the screen layout in 3 parts vertically, as you can see in the picture!

[Layout in 3 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltl5v.png)

The header row have a fixed height and the same for the footer row. The container row fill the remaining space on the screen and if this overflow the content, must show scroll.

I have the next approach:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.box {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: cyan;
}

.content {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: magenta;
}

.footer {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="box">
        <header class="header">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </header>
        <section id='view-port-list' class="content">
            <div id="content-div">
                 <h1>Content</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="footer">
            <h1>Footer</h1>
        </section>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

I need, when the content div overflows the maximum height, show the scroll.

Thanks and sorry for my english :s

Comment: Take a look at [Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/). More info [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/) and [here](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :)

HTML

```
<html>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">header</div>
        <div id="content">content</div>
        <div id="footer">footer</div>
    </div>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html,body,div{
padding:0;
margin:0;
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;}

html,body{
width:100%;
height:100%;}

#wrapper{
position:relative;
float:left;
width:100%;
min-height:100%;
padding:50px 0;}

#header{
position:fixed;
top:0;
width:100%;
height:50px;
background:#ccc;}

#content{
width:100%;}

#footer{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width:100%;
height:50px;
background:#ccc;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t360k3ke/